# How do I smoothly reduce a divs height to 0 in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, transition

I've tried and failed for hours now. The way I've done it is in `onMounted()` I first `div = document.GetElementByID`. Then, `div.style.height = '0';`. However, since this is being run from inside `onMounted()`, it doesn't animate or transition it, even though I have all the necessary Tailwind classes for it to do so (note that it successfully resizes the div to 0 height, but there's no animation or transition). I even tried to put the `div.style.height = '0'` into a seperate function outside `onMounted()` which didn't work. The only thing that animates or transitions is opacity. And only that. Why? Why not height or anything else? What do I have to do to make it work?

```
<template>
    <div v-if="props.state == 2" class="w-full bg-[#E7685D] text-black text-2xl overflow-hidden duration-500 ease-in-out" id="alert">
        <p class="text-center p-2">text</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted } from '@vue/runtime-core'

onMounted(() => {
    const alert = document.getElementById('alert');
    setTimeout(() => { alert.style.height = '0%', 5000 })
})

const props = defineProps({
    state: String
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not animating because of your wrong syntax for `setTimeout` function. `setTimeout(() => { alert.style.height = '0%', 5000 })`. You've to define `milliseconds` out of the function brackets `{...}` in case you want a `5 seconds` delay before execution of the `setTimeout` function. Given below is the right syntax for the `setTimeout` function.

[Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#syntax): `setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  alert.style.height = '0%'
}, 5000)
```

**Edited:**
I'm not sure! Maybe adding the transition/animation classes in the `setTimeout` will do the trick.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  alert.classList.add("duration-500", "ease-in-out")
  alert.style.height = '0%'
}, 5000)
```

If it didn't work, try moving lines up/down in the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: What I meant was that it resizes it successfully, but there's no animation or transition, even though I've specified it in the divs classes. Also, thanks for the setTimeout suggestion. It actually waits the correct amount of time now. Still doesn't transition, though. :(